# Node.js + Socket.io app - not work in heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

In my app not connects socket.io.


my app.js (server)

`app.set('port',3000)` 

`let server = app.listen(app.get('port'))`

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)`

`global.io = io`

index.js (client) 


`const socket = io.connect('https://xxx-my-secret-app.herokuapp.com')`

browser console


`POST https://evening-savannah-51961.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lmx1tkf 404 (Not Found)`


responce html


`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><h2></h2><pre></pre></body></html>`

dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "connect": "^3.6.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "express-formidable": "^1.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "gravatary": "^1.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.4",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "nodejs-gravatar": "^1.0.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport.socketio": "^3.7.0",
    "pnglib": "0.0.1",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta11",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.5.0"`


My application is a multi-user chat. For the client application I use Angular 4

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the port your server runs on differently.

Heroku sets the port your application runs on, and then binds it to the public port you expose. To get the port Heroku sets, you need to read process.env.PORT:

```
let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT) 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server) 
global.io = io
```

Comment: @МаксЛолин That's odd! Do you have any other code using `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
let server = app.listen(port) 
console.log(`server  listen :${port}`)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server) 
global.io = io;

Comment: server  listen :58098
2017-05-24T15:51:03.251965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-05-24T15:51:03.789086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lmx9qCJ" host=evening-savannah-51961.herokuapp.com request_id=224adc28-708b-4015-929d-f7ce39e2b047 fwd="178.255.42.236" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=152ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-05-24T15:51:03.748939+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 58098 is already in use

Comment: Did you use `express-generator` to create your app? Or do you have a bin/www file which could also be trying to start a server?